# Why must my global variable be declared as a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, global-variables, new-operator

When compiling my C++ program I receive no errors, however within unordered_map the hash function fails, attempting to mod by 0. (Line 345 of hashtable_policy.h of stl)

I've found a fix, but don't know why I'm having the problem to begin with.
My struct looks like this, (Sorry for the specific code.)

```
struct Player {
private:
    Entity& entity = entityManager->create();
public:
    Player() {
        entity.addComponent(new PositionComponent(0, 0)); // Add component uses the unordered map.
    }
};
Player playerOne; // Error perpetuates through constructor.
```

However, if I declare playerOne as a pointer, like so:

```
Player* playerOne;
```

and then call:

```
playerOne = new Player();
```

I do not have any issues.

I've been searching - with no success. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does `entityManager->create()` return a temporary. If so, you'll end up with a dangling reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a Player as a global, you've no idea if the entityManager (presumably another global) has been initialised yet - the order of initialisation of globals isn't defined.

When you use the pointer and initialise it with `new` (in main(), I presume), all the globals have been created by then, so the code works.

This highlights one of the reasons why global variables are a bad idea.

Comment: You are correct, entityManager is a global. Can you suggest another way to accomplish the same thing that doesn't require me to initialize with new?

Comment: Add a constructor argument to Player to take an Entity. In main(), Create the Entity object, then create the Player object, passing in the Entity just created. The real issue is using global variables - instead of all other code accessing a global Player, pass the created Player instance into them.